# Docker cannot mount volume over existing file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am doing this on a AWS Linux Instance

```
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5/1.9.1
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5/1.9.1
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Whenever I try to `docker-compose up -d` with the following docker-compose.yml (this is an excerpt)

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:2.1.1
  command: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - "9200:9200"       
  - "9300:9300"
  volumes:
  - ./elk/es/staging.yml:/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
  links: 
  - kibana
  volumes_from:
  - es-data

es-data:
  image: elasticsearch:2.1.1
  command: "true"
  volumes:
  - /usr/share/elasticsearch/
  - /etc/default/elasticsearch
  - /var/lib/elasticsearch/
  - /var/log/elasticsearch
```

I'll receive this error:

```
Recreating es-data_1
ERROR: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/33111596cd765c4220c65ea7cc35df4a6c295a860e4ad94294c7ee985da6ea7c/rootfs/etc/default/elasticsearch
```

I've tried bypassing this error by removing the volumes from es-data, but that is not ideal as I'm using it as a data only container.

I've tried removing all the volumes available on the system using `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)`, but that removes all of the volumes except one that I am not sure how to force remove.

Ideal situation would be to allow me to reuse that volume (which I'm assuming is orphaned at this point). Second ideal situation would be able to remove the volume and be able to create a new one.

If I was doing this on my personal machine, I would take the easier approach of recreating the docker-machine I am using as a clean slate, but I don't want to do that on my AWS instance.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://serverfault.com/questions/683910/removing-docker-data-volumes

Comment: I've tried that approach and it hasn't worked either. I'll try again tomorrow in the morning.